# Exposing an enum that is not in any operation

Tags: .net, wcf, enums

How expose a enum that is not in any operation? Can i do this in wcf?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not in any operation"? And what do you mean by "expose" in this context?

Comment: Expose a enum type in a wcf service to a client wcf that is not in any OperationContract how return type or parameter.

Comment: If it's not in use, why expose it?

Comment: understood. It really does not need to be exposed. Sorry anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer you are hoping for, bit not AFAIK (unless you handle all the xsd ect manually, which is a lot of work). The most pragmatic option (to expose such an enum) is probably to introduce a dummy method that includes the enum, but which you never expect to be called in reality (just throw an Exception).